# Springer Nature Template + Package problem

Tags: glossaries, todonotes

I just started working on a journal article which is supposed to be submitted according to the `sn-jnl` template. I therefore [downloaded the zip](https://www.springernature.com/la/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support) and started adding my content.

Unfortunately I soon discovered that the `glossaries` package and the `todonotes` package break the compilation.
The error is reproducible even with their [Overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq).

- download zip/open overleaf template -> compiles well
- add `\usepackage{glossaries}` in the head -> error

The same problem occurs with `\usepackage{todonotes}`.
Does anybody have a solution to this issue?

I consider these packages to be rather common and never had any issues with any other conference/journal template, so I am confused as to why this happens.

I'm aware that there are alternatives to these two, but I'm worried that other (more important) packages are going to raise similar issues.

Error:

```
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 79.

 
‪/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty, 25‬
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.25 
     
The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.
```

EDIT:
Here's a screenshot of what I see, including the first page which is the actual problem (it's garbage)

[image]

---

*UPDATE: (Quick) Fix*

Thanks to [@simon-dispa 's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614796/70862), I learned where to look in the `sn-jnl.cls`. It seems that actually the problem is on line 311: `\usepackage{program}` causes issues.

The good part: When uncommenting this line, the compilation (and everything else) works smoothly.

Now to the bad part: I have to modify the official Springer template to get things running. I personally do not need it here, but clearly I'm modifying things that I shouldn't, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had this problem, and found an answer in another [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619280/springer-nature-2021-class-causes-error-when-writing-x) on Tex.Stockexchange.

For self-containedness, I include here the answer (courtesy of the user [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle))

> The class includes the program package which makes some unfortunate choices including globally making | active, it provides a command
>
> `\normalbaroutside` which you can issue in the preamble then | only
> gets the special meaning inside program environments.

So the **solution** is to call `\normalbaroutside` in the preamble before loading `glossaries/tikz/todonotes`. The advantage is that this way `sn-jnl.cls` can remain **unchanged.**

Comment: Wowza, that fixed the error with including the 'fp' package in the springer template, as well. Nice.