# Springer Nature 2021 class causes error when writing $|x|$

Tags: springer, springernature

The following simple adaption of the Springer Nature template causes an error. I can't write `[x|` or `|\zeta|`, for example, without causing an error. What is the cause of that error and how can it be fixed?

The Springer Nature template can be found here: [Springer Nature Template](https://www.springernature.com/de/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support)

I am aware of a similar [unanswered question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615388/cannot-use-in-springers-nature-latex-template) on this site, where some comments suggest replacing | by `\vert`. I don't think I should accommodate such bizarre behavior unless there is a good reason why writing `|` is inherently wrong.

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\jyear{2021}
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}\newtheorem{example}{Example}\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\title[Article Title]{Article Title}
\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}
\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
\author[1,2]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
\affil[3]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{610101}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
\abstract{Nothing to abstract here.}
\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}
\maketitle
\section{This works well}
$x$

$[x]$

$|x|$

$\zeta$

$[\zeta]$

\section{Those lines cause errors}
$|x]$

$[x|$

$|\zeta|$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please cite the exact error message. Actually, neither `|` or `\vert` is the proper symbol to use for absolute values (try `$|-1|$` and compare it to `$\lvert - 1\rvert$`).

Comment: @daleif: There is everything to reproduce the error. Maybe my latex distribution is corrupted, then it's good to know if others cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: @daleif Thank you for pointing out `\lvert -1 \rvert` I was not aware of this.

Comment: Not many people do. It might was to check the mathtools package, it has better facilities to build a `\abs` macro (disclaimer, I maintain it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The class includes the `program` package which makes some unfortunate choices including globally making `|` active, it provides a command

```
 \normalbaroutside
```

which you can issue in the preamble then `|` only gets the special meaning inside program environments.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error.

For |X| use $\lvert X \vert$

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!