# Latex not recognizing | symbol

Tags: symbols, compilation-error

I have trouble compiling a document. The document compiles when using standard "article" documentclass, but fails using the format for Springer journals.

I narrowed it down to the symbol "|" (the straight bar). Personally I do not use \mid for that (it takes more characters and adds more space around it), but the symbol found on the keyboard. It usually works, but now it doesn't and I don't know why. Do you have any tips?

---

In order to get a minimal working example: download the Springer template here: https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

Then simply:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences 
\begin{document}
$|\Omega|$ 
\end{document}
```

---

The error message:

`Missing $ inserted. $|\Omega`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an invisible character somewhere in that line?  What's the smallest example you can make with `|` that compiles with article, but not with Springer?  Can you post that?  Can you also post the error you're getting?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619283/586

Comment: Thank you! The question containing the answer did not appear in my searches.

Comment: always easier to search for the answer than the question, so @TorbjørnT. had an advantage while searching:-)